# Actualizar base de datos desde javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, phpmyadmin

Estoy utilizando el Sandbox de PayPal para realizar pagos ficticios en un proyecto y lo que intento hacer es que cuando PayPal me devuelve que el pago se ha realizado, cambiar el estado del usuario es la base de datos de inactivo a activo.
Desde aqui es desde se realiza el pago:

```
<?php
# Set page title and display header section.
require_once('includes/header.php');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <title>Webflix</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="login">
                <div class="container">
                    <h3 class="title">Become a Webflix Premium Member</h3>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>If you want to enjoy the best movies and TV series on Webflix, become a Premium Member. For £99.00 a year you'll have access to each and every one of them anywhere, anytime.<p>
                        <br>
                        <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=GBP"></script>
                        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
                        <script>
                        paypal.Buttons({
                            // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
                            createOrder: (data, actions) => {
                            return actions.order.create({
                                purchase_units: [{
                                amount: {
                                    value: '99.00' // Can also reference a variable or function
                                }
                                }]
                            });
                            },
                            // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
                            onApprove: (data, actions) => {
                            return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                                // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
                                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                                const transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                                alert(`Thank you for your payment! ${transaction.status}: ${transaction.id}\n\nEnjoy the best content for a year `);
                                // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
                                // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                                // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                                // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
                            });
                            }
                        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Lo he intentando hacer con ajax, pero cada vez que he puesto algun codigo dentro del script, me han desaparecido los botones.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Desde ahí puedes mandar a actualizar la BD en el servidor mediante una petición Ajax o usando la nueva API Fetch de Javascript.

Comment: @A.Cedano hola. En cuanto a lo de Ajax, lo he intentado pero cada vez que he puesto codigo dentro del script, me desaparecen los botones de PayPal.
Por otro lado, acabo de leer un poco mas del API Fetch. Seria algo asi como poner let('url de la pagina php donde hago el query para el update')?

En cualquier caso, donde se pondria el codigo dentro del script?

Gracias!

Comment: Dado que el script tiene un `return` sería mejor poner el código Ajax donde se recibe ese `return`  y si no funciona de la forma esperada será porque cometes algún error al agregar el nuevo código o porque no lo pones en el lugar correcto. Si quieres usar la API Fetch, [aquí tienes la doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: $.ajax ( {
                                    url: 'update_status.php',
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: {status: 'Active'}
                                });

Este es el trozo de codigo que pongo justo despues del alert que esta en el return... pero no me actualiza la BD.

Comment: Bueno, al final he cogido por la tangente: he hecho un redirect a otra pagina donde se hace el cambio desde un mysqli_query.

Comment: Eso es lo que debería hacer `update_status.php`, si no lo hace, debes ver por qué no lo hace y corregirlo. Con Ajax no tiene sentido redirigir, ese es el propósito del archivo que pones en el parámetro `url`. Además, a tu petición le falta la parte del `success` o `done`, donde verificas el resultado de lo ocurrido.